# array_search does not work properly in foreach

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

For some reason when I put this array through foreach it does not work properly.
What am I doing wrong?

```
array (size=2)'Final' => array (size=1)'sender' => array (size=1)'asd' => array (size=2)...'Hos' => array (size=1)'sender' => array (size=1)'asd' => array (size=2)...

foreach($sent_app_groups['title'] as $k => $v) {
    $pill_title = array_search($sent_app_groups['title'][$k],$sent_app_groups['title']); 
    echo $pill_title;
}
```

The result should be:

> Final  Hos

But I always get:

> Final  Final

Comment: write down the exact array statement, so that you can get a better and effective solution.

Comment: Can you add the `print_f()` of the array, IMO its much easier to read

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is the right way to do it, silly me :P
But still I don't get it, shouldn't it do the same thing with array_search?

`foreach($sent_app_groups['title'] as $k => $v) {
    $pill_title = $k; 
    echo $pill_title;
}`